# Can't use CssNano "discardDuplicates" as standalone plugin

Tags: vite, postcss, cssnano

I'm using Vite as build tool.
Vite has an integrated `postCSS` config option that you can set in `vite.config.js`, so I'm using this to load `cssNano` as a plugin :

```
//vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    //other config
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [ cssnano ]

        }
    }
})
```

This works fine (minification, etc) as it is as `cssNano` uses the "default" configuration when loaded with no config.

> "...Without configuration, cssnano runs with the default preset."
> https://cssnano.co/docs/config-file/

The issue occurs when I want to use individual plugins/optimisation, particularly "discardDuplicates".(But I didn't test every optimisation on it's own)
`eg:`

```
//vite.config.js
import discardUnused from 'postcss-discard-unused';
import colormin from 'postcss-colormin';
import discardDuplicates from 'postcss-discard-duplicates';

export default defineConfig({
    //other config
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [
                cssnano(
                    {
                        plugins: [discardUnused,colormin,discardDuplicates]
                    }),
            ]

        }
    }
})
```

In this code above, `discardUnused` and `colormin` works fine.
My unused `@keyframes` rule is discarded by `discardUnused`
as in the Docs ([cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/discardunused/](https://cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/discardunused/))\

and my `background: hsl(134, 50%, 50%);` rule is transformed into `background: #40bf5e;` by `colormin`
as in the Docs (https://cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/colormin/)\

But the duplicate selectors I use to test `discardDuplicates` (https://cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/discardduplicates/)
are not merged together.
May be I missed something (I'm kind of a newbie in js build tools), because everything works fine when I use the `default` CssNano preset.\

Input :

```
/** duplicate body for testing discardDuplicates **/
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}
body {
    /** hsl value for testing colormin **/
    background: hsl(134, 50%, 50%);
}
/** unused keyframe for testing discardUnused **/
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Expected Output :

```
/** duplicate body for testing discardDuplicates **/
body {
    display:flex;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #40bf5e;
}
/** unused keyframe for testing **/
```

Actual output :

```
/** duplicate body for testing discardDuplicates **/
body{
    display:flex;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    /** hsl value for testing colormin **/
    background: #40bf5e;
}
/** unused keyframe for testing discardUnused **/
```